# Make a new array with common elements in two arrays

Tags: java

I have to create a method, that returns an array with common elements from two different arrays. I am aware there are lots of questions about this, but mine is a little bit different from those as I have to create a new array.

I've tried to first count how many common elements there are from two arrays, and then create an array with size the number of that.

After, I tried to set the new array to the common elements using a for loop.

```
public static int [] commonElements(int []a, int [] b){
      int count=0;
      for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
         for(int j=0;j<b.length;j++) {
           if(a[i] == b[j]) {
             count++;
           }
        }
     }
     int []array= new int[count];

     for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<b.length;j++) {
           if(a[i] == b[j]) {
              for (int k=0; k<count; k++){

                 array[k]=a[i];
             }
          }
       }
    }
    return array;
 }
```

This returns four -1's, so it doesn't work. 
I am also required not to use arraylist, so I have no idea how to make this code complete.
The expected value with

```
  // checking common elements
  System.out.println ("\nLooking for common elements in the arrays "); 
  int [] arr3= {56, -21, -5, 7, 10,  21, 2, -1};
  int [] arr4= {-1, -56, 5, 21, 3 , 7, 4, -6, 2, 90};
  int [] result4 = commonElements(arr3, arr4);
  System.out.println (Arrays.toString(arr3));
  System.out.println (Arrays.toString(arr4));  
  System.out.print ("\nCommon elements array:  ");
  System.out.println (Arrays.toString(result4));
```

in the main is

```
     Looking for common elements in the arrays 
      [56, -21, -5, 7, 10, 21, 2, -1]
      [-1, -56, 5, 21, 3, 7, 4, -6, 2, 90]

      Common elements array:  [7, 21, 2, -1]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Declare `k=0` outside for loop and increment in loop `array[k++]=a[i];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, instead of `int []array= new array[count];` you need `new int[count];` - second, instead of a third inner loop when populating your output keep a position index and increment it when you encounter a duplicate. Like,

```
public static int[] commonElements(int[] a, int[] b) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {
            if (a[i] == b[j]) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    int[] array = new int[count];
    int p = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {
            if (a[i] == b[j]) {
                array[p] = a[i];
                p++;
            }
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

Alternatively, if using Java 8+, the above can be simplified by filtering on an `IntStream` of the two arrays. Like,

```
return Arrays.stream(a).filter(i -> Arrays.stream(b).anyMatch(x -> x == i))
        .toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use a list to store the intermediate intersecting values, and then convert to an array at the end of the method:

```
public static int[] commonElements(int[] a, int[] b) {
    List<Integer> common = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i=0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j < b.length; j++) {
            if (a[i] == b[j]) {
                common.add(a[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    int[] array = common.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
    return array;
}
```

If you don't want to record duplicates, then replace `common` with `Set<Integer>`.